# Permissions problem in Ubuntu when accessing airflow webserver as root and non-root user

Tags: server, permissions, mysql, root

I have followed this guide to install MySQL for aiflow on Ubuntu 22.04.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04

I have created a non-root administrative user (myusername) who is able to do sudo commands and set up this user's password.

then I proceeded with installing airflow as this user.

Now one thing I notice is that my Python seems to be installed in a different directory from my airflow.

```
#python
myusername@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:/root$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Aug 18 11:39 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Aug 18 11:39 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.10-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5912936 Nov  2 18:53 /usr/bin/python3.10

#airflow
drwxrwxr-x 2 myusername myusername 4096 Nov 20 14:17 __pycache__
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myusername myusername 3472 Nov 20 14:17 activate-global-python-argcomplete
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myusername myusername  215 Nov 20 14:17 airflow
-rwxrwxr-x 1 myusername myusername  213 Nov 20 14:17 alembic
```

At first Ubuntu did recognize any airflow commands such as 'airflow info' and see my files with 'ls -l ~/.local/bin' until I have added 'PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin' to the end of the ~/.bashrc  file.

However, I am now having an error with opening a webserver with my  non-root admin user:

```
myusername@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:/root$ airflow webserver -p 8080

Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root'
[2022-11-20 18:11:05,198] {webserver_command.py:217} ERROR - No response from gunicorn master within 120 seconds
[2022-11-20 18:11:05,199] {webserver_command.py:218} ERROR - Shutting down webserver
```

In addition, I cant do 'myuserame@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:/root$ cd airflow/'
as it says:

```
bash: cd: airflow/: Permission denied
```

When I try to switch to root with 'su root' it is asking me for a password which I do not know (I have probably reset this password when altering'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH auth_socket).

Can someone help me with this?   I'm not v experienced with Ubuntu and have it installed on WSL2.

Comment: Which `root` are you referring to? The root account of the server or the root account for MySQL? The MySQL `root` account *cannot* be used by applications.

Comment: it is the root which appears when I open up Ubuntu. I can see 'root@LAPTOP-28BMMQV7:~#', and from that I switch to 'su myusername'.